# expire desktop_url generated through branch SDK after one time use

Tags: branch.io

I want to expire web link (`$desktop_url`) generated through branch after clicking one time.

I tried using option of `$one_time_use` setting to true and set `type` to 1 but it is not working.

I am using https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api
for link creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from Branch.io team. The "$one_time_use" control parameter is not supported anymore. You can use "$link_exp_date" and set the value in epoch date to make the link expire after a particular date.

Once the link expires, it will stop deep linking but will be capable of opening the app and websites.

Comment: is there any way to stop opening `$desktop_url` also?