# How to create one time use deep links?

Tags: branch.io

I'm finding conflicting information on creating one time use deep links.

[expire desktop_url generated through branch SDK after one time use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977778/expire-desktop-url-generated-through-branch-sdk-after-one-time-use/49980169#49980169)

The documentation on "type" says "Must be an int. Set to 1 to limit deep link to a single use. Set to 2 to make the link show up under Quick Links while adding $marketing_title to data. Does not work with the Native SDKs." (https://docs.branch.io/links/integrate/)

I created a link using the included JSON with a POST to https://api2.branch.io/v1/url.

```
{
  "branch_key": "*********************",
  "data": {
    "entityId": "282fd3da-5200-45f4-80a2-4f3a1c36bff6",
    "$link_exp_date": 1567271700000
  },
  "type": 1,
  "feature": "test_feature",
  "tags": []
}
```

I expected the URL to be available for one time use. However I am able to successfully use the link multiple times until it expires. And retrieving the link using GET https://api.branch.io/v1/url doesn't return any properties that indicate the link was used.

Answer (score 0):

Even before creating a deep link and testing, you need to integrate the Branch SDK in your [respective app](https://docs.branch.io/resources/native-sdks-and-plugins/) (Android, iOS etc).

The simple way to [create a deep link](https://docs.branch.io/links/quick-links/) is via dashboard and test this when the app is installed.

Comment: I'm using the Deep Linking API as stated above. My question is why does setting the "type" to 1 not make the magic link a one time use link as stated in the documentation.